# Where is the source code for Apache Ant "Apply" task?

Tags: ant

I am looking for the source code that implements the `apply` task in ant. I have been search through the sources at:

```
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ant-core/trunk/
```

Alas, `grep` and `find` have not revealed its whereabouts! I must be looking in the wrong place. Anyone know where this source file is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file [org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/defaults.properties](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/defaults.properties) gives the mapping between XML element names and the implementing classes. In the case of `apply` it looks like the class is `Transform`, which in turn is a no-op subclass of `ExecuteOn` (as `execon` is a deprecated alias for `apply`).